# SQL Query get records between 10pm to 6am

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to ask on how to retrieve records, from a database table, with a time range from 10pm to 6am.

Comment: Try to do some research before posting. This is really a basic question.

Comment: This is a relatively basic question, but the reason I'm downvoting it is because you have not provided enough information for anyone to give you an answer.

To make the question appropriate, you should, at the least, describe or provide the structure of the table(s) you want to query.  In addition, you may want to specify if you are querying using SQL, LINQ, or some other accessor.

Comment: Same home work problem here with a few answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406235/select-date-and-time-in-sql-10pm-up-to-6am-everyday?noredirect=1#comment77774538_45406235

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE creation_time BETWEEN '2013-05-10 10:00:00' AND '2013-05-10 18:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it will works but i forgot something. The requirement was get the minimum value and maximum for the datetime range and also to group by that datetime range.

Comment: You would need to do a group by on a key column you need and select the min and max value of the column you want using the time constraints provided and the MIN() MAX() functions.

Comment: By the way the query is not between like  2013-05-10 10:00:00 and 2013-05-10 18:00:00. Its the next day between 2013-05-10 22:00:00 and 2013-05-11 06:00:00 with grouping the datetime range. Thanks to you guys. I really appreciate.