# SELECT Date and Time in SQL 10PM up to 6AM Everyday

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datetime

```
 SELECT scandate from FPI where scandate BETWEEN '2017-07-20' and '2017-07-25' DATEPART(hh,[scandate]) >= 22 AND DATEPART(hh,[scandate]) < 6
```

but i get nothing ...

```
  SELECT scandate from FPI where scandate BETWEEN '2017-07-20' and '2017-07-25' DATEPART(hh,[scandate]) >= 14 AND DATEPART(hh,[scandate]) < 22
```

2pm to 10pm is working but for 10pm to 6am its not working...TIA

Comment: Remember that if you are going to 6 AM the next date, you should do a dateadd(day,scandate ,1) and then check that.

Comment: How are you getting times between midnight at 6AM if you don't add one to the date?

Comment: its between 5days so no need to add one day ..

Answer (score 1):

You need `OR` in the first query:

```
SELECT scandate 
FROM FPI 
WHERE scandate BETWEEN '2017-07-20' and '2017-07-25' AND
      (DATEPART(hour, scandate) >= 22 OR DATEPART(hour, scandate) < 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `OR`,

```
 SELECT scandate from FPI where scandate BETWEEN '2017-07-20' and '2017-07-25' DATEPART(hh,[scandate]) >= 22 OR DATEPART(hh,[scandate]) < 6;
```

Comment: its wrong i do get the data .. but the output is 470k

Comment: THank you guys i solve the problem
i just add OPEN and CLOSE () between datepart
              SELECT scandate from FPI where scandate BETWEEN '2017-07-20' and '2017-07-25' DATEPART(hh,[scandate]) >= 22 OR  DATEPART(hh,[scandate]) < 6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one to the date:

```
SELECT scandate 
FROM FPI 
WHERE scandate BETWEEN '2017-07-20' and dateadd(day,1,'2017-07-25') AND
  (DATEPART(hour, scandate) >= 22 OR DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(day,1, scandate)) < 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT scandate 
 FROM FPI 
 WHERE scandate BETWEEN '2017-07-20' and '2017-07-25' AND
      (DATEPART(hour, scandate) >= 22 OR DATEPART(hour, scandate) < 6)